# Please translate into English: "Stultorum infinita esse genera"

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

This copper engraving is from a 1628 Italian book. Link to image of page:
[WDB - Wolfenbütteler Digitale Bibliothek - drucke/uk-70](http://diglib.hab.de/drucke/uk-70/start.htm).

Answer (score 3):

There are infinite types of fools.